# Why is all incoming sms/phone call data repeated in Twilio request?

Tags: twilio

I'm seeing all the pertinent data for an incoming phone call and sms repeated when I receive requests from Twilio to handle the communication:

```
{
  AccountSid: [ 'xxx', 'xxx' ],
  ToZip: [ '30680', '30680' ],
  FromState: [ 'NY', 'NY' ],
  Called: [ '+111', '+111' ],
  FromCountry: [ 'US', 'US' ],
  CallerCountry: [ 'US', 'US' ],
  CalledZip: [ '30680', '30680' ],
  Direction: [ 'inbound', 'inbound' ],
  FromCity: [ 'NEW YORK', 'NEW YORK' ],
  CalledCountry: [ 'US', 'US' ],
  CallerState: [ 'NY', 'NY' ],
  CallSid: [ 'xxx', 'xxx' ],
  CalledState: [ 'GA', 'GA' ],
  From: [ '+222', '+222' ],
  CallerZip: [ '10028', '10028' ],
  FromZip: [ '10028', '10028' ],
  ApplicationSid: [ 'xxx', 'xxx' ],
  CallStatus: [ 'ringing', 'ringing' ],
  ToCity: [ 'STATHAM', 'STATHAM' ],
  ToState: [ 'GA', 'GA' ],
  To: [ '+111', '+111' ],
  ToCountry: [ 'US', 'US' ],
  CallerCity: [ 'NEW YORK', 'NEW YORK' ],
  ApiVersion: [ '2010-04-01', '2010-04-01' ],
  Caller: [ '+222', '+222' ],
  CalledCity: [ 'STATHAM', 'STATHAM' ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because my webserver redirects all http traffic to https. The redirect causes twilio to repeat the information (like the to and from number). I hope this saves someone the trouble of figuring this out in the future.